# Grease pencil file size

Tags: blend-files, file-format

So I started working on a traditional 2d horse gallop. Each horse has 12 frames of 4 layers and i have 6 horses over a 400 frames animation.

However, my file size is 1.6gb ONE POINT SIX GIGABITES!!!!!  I have removed orphan data and cleared unused data, I have also used the compressed function which does not help.

The whole animation has become so slow even to preview. Is there a way to reduce my file size? apart from the methods I have already tried. Never knew grease pencil used so much data.

Really need help. Rendering is taking about 6sec per frame.

Comment: Have you try write your blend file in compressed format? When saving, check out RHS panel, there is a compress option. Default to not checked. If the file size didn't change much, then unfortunately the file size might not be able to deal w/o redesign the grease pencil system

Comment: I don't know much about grease pencil and file size but I imagine the size is dependent on the complexity of one 'frame' of your animation. It might help others (who know about these things) to determine whether 1.6Gb is reasonable in your situation if they can see an example of a typical frame - perhaps edit your question to include some screenshots/images.

Comment: @susu :: The problem might be easier to investigate with a sample dot-blend file.  The issue might be related to some unofficial add-on(s).

Comment: Another wasted bounty.